# Creating simple document with JDOM

Tags: java, document, jdom

I am trying to create a simple Document with Jdom.
I strictly followed the instructions given on

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm

I cannot understand why, no matter what I do, I end up with a `[document:null]`.

This is my code :

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.jdom2.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Network {

    public Document SetToXml() throws Exception {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory DBF =        
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = DB.newDocument();

            Element root = doc.createElement("network");
            root.setAttribute("name", Name);
            doc.appendChild(root);
        }
    }
}
```

When I inspect the `doc` variable, it always contains `[document:null]`.

Is there any way out or should I give up ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say, no need to worry :)
The `"[document:null]"` string which your debugger is showing you is only the `toString()` - representation of the `document` object. I do not yet understand, why it actually looks like this, but I verified that regardless of this, the document actually has the `"netwrok"` element you specified and also the `name` attribute you are assigning to it.